# how to change Primefaces Picklist height with CSS?

Tags: html, css

We would like to change the height of `<ul ...>` tag. There is no `id` in `<ul...>` tag.
We can only know the `id` of the html table. The following `html` code is generated by `JSF Primefaces`.

[Primefaces PickList](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/picklist.jsf)

```
<table id="roleEntryForm:resourceItem" class="ui-picklist ui-widget">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul class="ui-widget-content ui-picklist-list ui-picklist-target ui-corner-all ui-sortable"></ul>
                <select id="roleEntryForm:resourceItem_target" class="ui-helper-hidden" multiple="true" name="roleEntryForm:resourceItem_target"></select>
            </td>   
            ....
        </tr>
        .....
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

I used CSS as below but it does not work.

```
#roleEntryForm:resourceItem tr td ul {
    height:500px;
}

.ui-picklist .ui-picklist-list {
    height: 200px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
.ui-corner-all {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
.ui-widget-content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #A8A8A8;
    color: #4F4F4F;
}
ul {
}

.ui-widget {
    font-size: 98% !important;
}
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use the `class` instead?

Comment: I changed the height to 400px and it worked for me.  I changed the height inside the `.ui-picklist .ui-picklist-list` block.

Comment: Can you try without the colon in the id, the css parser might be thinking it's a pseudo-class

Comment: I cannot change the id, because of id is generate by JSF(naming container).  it is used colon.

Answer (score 4):

Belwo is code to change the height and width of picklist primeface . This works for me

```
<h:head>
<style>
.ui-picklist .ui-picklist-list{
height:500px;
width: 500px
}

</style>
</h:head>
```

Comment: it will effect all of picklist. In my project there are so many picklist

Comment: then you add a specific styleclass for the picklists you want to change, see the example from optimus prime at http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9573 (styleClass="p1", styleClass="p2" and styleClass="p3"). Surya's answer is right

Answer (score 1):

this works for me on chrome,
but not in internet explorer

`.ui-picklist .ui-picklist-list {
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
}`

Comment: It will effect all of picklist. In my project there are so many picklist.

Answer (score 0):

just add class name of your picklist in css. It would be so `.className.ui-picklist`